# React Excel Workbook dataset

Tags: reactjs, excel

My problem is I am trying to dynamically create sheets using react-excel-workbook and I have an array of columns to be generated when the user clicks download providing empty table content values.

```
    const columns = ['CA','CB','CC','CD','CE','CF','sCG'];
    const generate = () => {
      columns.map((data) => {
        return (
        <Workbook filename="test.xlsx" element={<button className="btn btn-lg btn- 
           primary">download</button>}>
          <Workbook.Sheet data={columns} name="Sheet A">
           <Workbook.Column label={data} value={''}/>
          </Workbook.Sheet>
        </Workbook>
        );
      })
    }
```

But I am getting a warning:

```
react.development.js:220 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `object` supplied to `Sheet`, expected an array
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to take Workbook.Sheet out of the map and It works when I do it like this.

```
  <Workbook.Sheet data={columns} name="Sheet A">
     {
       columns.map((data, key) => {
        return (
         <Workbook.Column label={data} value={''} key={key}/>
        );
       })
    }
  </Workbook.Sheet>
```